# Couldn't launch browser when using ChromeDriverManager

Tags: python, browser

While using the below chromedrive- Manager(Also imported-ChromeDriverManager) getting the error. It was working earlier.

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

```
ERROR:

 open(targetpath, "wb") as target:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\KANI\\.wdm\\drivers\\chromedriver\\79.0.3945.36\\win32\\chromedriver.exe'
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you set right of chromedriver.exe set to as administrator

[image]